# Duvida - Query (Não trazer um determinado registro)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Boa tarde Galera!

Seguinte, abaixo é uma query onde era para trazer todos os chamados que tem a descrição ''Bloquear Cliente - Inadimplente' and com id = 572 (clientes bloqueados), porém, nessa consulta tem alguns clientes com já foram desbloqueados, ou seja, já tem um chamado com outra descrição. Queria saber como trazer somente os registros com os clientes bloqueados sem nenhum chamado com desbloqueio. Abaixo é a query que eu tentei.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
*
FROM Tarefa T
WHERE 
T.TarID in(select TarID from Tarefa where T.TarTitulo = 'Bloquear Cliente - Inadimplente' AND T.TarTipID = 572
and T.TarID not in (select TarID from Tarefa where TarTipID = 574 and TarTitulo = 'Desbloqueio Cliente'))
```

Comment: Qual a tabela/campo de clientes?

Comment: A Tabela é somente Tarefa e o campo cliente é usuidcliente

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, o seu problema é que clientes que já foram desbloqueados estão aparecendo, então existe um campo de data nessa tabela Tarefa? nesse caso você só quer executar o filtro sobre o último chamados dos clientes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a cláusula `EXISTS` em conjunto com o `NOT` para descobrir os clientes que não tenham chamado de desbloqueio:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM Tarefa T
 WHERE T.TarTitulo = 'Bloquear Cliente - Inadimplente'
   AND T.TarTipID = 572
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM Tarefa t2
                   WHERE t2.TarTitulo = 'Desbloqueio Cliente'
                     AND t2.TarTipID = 574
                     AND t2.usuidcliente = t.usuidcliente)
```

Comment: ôpa meu jovem. Deu certo cara. Muitíssimo obg!